# How to group values from Node's props by its other props in Cypher Neo4j?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I'll describe my data model, and some things that I want to achieve. 
I have Neo4j as db, data structure is immutable for now, so advices like "just create other Nodes with changed label" is not for my situation, in advance I'm sorry!

In Neo4j I have `Node:Category`, `Node:Goods`, `Node:Property`. Goods could have many relations with Property. For example: `(:Goods {name: "Chair"})-[:PROP]-(:Property)`. This `Node:Goods` related to two `Node:Properties` - price and material. As you might have guessed - I have a lot of `Node:Goods` and each one is related to price and material `Node:Property`.

I need to build frontend client for this structure with ability to filter `Node:Goods` by its related `Node:Property`. For example I need all `Node:Goods` that have relation to `Node:Property` with `{name:"Price"}` and `{value: >40, <100}`. I've asked about this here and get the great answer by @InverseFalcon:

```
...
WITH g, size([(g)-[:Prop]-(p:Property) WHERE p.name = "Price" AND 190 < p.value < 320 | p]) > 0 as priceRange 
WHERE priceRange
...
```

This solution works perfectly when I know what and how to filter. My question is how can I group all Node:Propery values by its names, to find max and min and variants to pass them to frontend filters?

My `Node:Property` looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"Price",
    "type":"num", //text, bool
    "value":245
}
```

I expected smth like this (but no matter if response would be not so pretty):

```
{ 
    "Category": "Chair",
    "Goods": 157,
    "Properties": [
        { "Name": "Material", "type":"text", "variants": "Metal", "Oak", "Maple" },
        { "Name": "Price", "type": "num", "min": 25, "max": 490 },
        { "Name": "InStock", "type": "bool" },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I tried to achieve this by UNWIND and FOREACH, but there is no way I found to make RETURN inside FOREACH. I appreciate any help and tips, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CASE when aggregating:

```
MATCH (C:Category)
OPTIONAL MATCH (C)-[:Good]->(G:Goods)-[:Prop]->(P:Property)
WITH C, 
     count(DISTINCT G) AS cnt, 
     P.Name AS name, P.type AS type, 
     CASE WHEN P.type = "num" THEN min(P.value) ELSE null END AS min, 
     CASE WHEN P.type = "num" THEN max(P.value) ELSE null END AS max,
     CASE WHEN P.type = "text" THEN collect(P.value) ELSE null END AS variants
WITH C.name AS name, cnt, 
     {name: name, type: type, min: min, max: max, variants: variants } AS prop
RETURN {Category: name, Goods: cnt, Properties: collect(prop)} AS category
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `min()` and `max()` aggregation functions when you're dealing with `num` type :Properties.

Tackling these three variants, you might use a query like this:

```
MATCH (good:Good)
WITH good
OPTIONAL MATCH (good)-[:PROP]-(p:Property {type:'text'})
WITH good, p.name as name, collect(p.value) as variants
WITH good, collect({name:name, type:'text', variants:variants}) as properties
OPTIONAL MATCH (good)-[:PROP]-(p:Property {type:'num'})
WITH good, properties, p.name as name, min(p.value) as min, max(p.value) as max
WITH good, properties + collect({name:name, type:'num', min:min, max:max}) as properties
WITH good, properties + [(good)-[:PROP]-(p:Property {type:'bool'}) | p {.name, type:'bool'}] as properties
RETURN good, properties
```